# Update several attributes only in DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, serverless-framework

Use below codes, I successfully update an item

https://github.com/serverless/examples/blob/master/aws-node-rest-api-with-dynamodb/todos/update.js#L22-L37

```
const params = {
  TableName: process.env.DYNAMODB_TABLE,
  Key: {
    id: event.pathParameters.id,
  },
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    '#todo_text': 'text',
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':text': data.text,
    ':checked': data.checked,
    ':updatedAt': timestamp,
  },
  UpdateExpression: 'SET #todo_text = :text, checked = :checked, updatedAt = :updatedAt',
  ReturnValues: 'ALL_NEW',
};
```

Then I add more attributes:

```
  const params = {
    TableName: process.env.DYNAMODB_TABLE,
    Key: {
      id: event.pathParameters.id,
    },
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      '#user_name': 'name',
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':name': data.name,
      ':email': data.email,
      ':username': data.username,
      ':password': data.password,
      ':checked': data.checked,
      ':updatedAt': timestamp,
    },
    UpdateExpression: 'SET #user_name = :name, email = :email, username = :username, password = :password, checked = :checked, updatedAt = :updatedAt',
    ReturnValues: 'ALL_NEW',
  };
```

Above codes work fine if I feed all attributes.

```
$ cat test/user-1.json
{
  "name": "Bob",
  "email": "bob@example.com",
  "username": "bob",
  "password": "adfdsfdsf",
  "checked": false
}
```

But if I only want to update part of them, since I needn't update email and password every time, I got error `Couldn't fetch the user item.`

```
$ cat test/user-1.json
{
  "name": "Bob",
  "username": "bob-1",
  "checked": false
}

$ curl -X PUT ${url}/${id} --data '@test/user-1.json'
Couldn't fetch the user item.
```

So how to change the code that I don't have to update all attributes.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is super old, but in case someone else comes across this, I built basically a params factory -- I have a function that returns my params and my `ExpressionAttributeValues` object and `UpdateExpression` string only comprise of the variables that pass my validation

Answer (score 0):

The Update API call will not work as the data.email and data.password are undefined.

I would suggest altering the UpdateExpression when you don't need to update those attributes.